# How do I reactivate USB devices using WIN API?

Tags: winapi, usb

Do you know how to reactivate USB devices?

WIN API [`CM_Request_Device_Eject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539806%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function can eject USB device,

but how to reactivate it?

I tried to use [`CM_Setup_DevNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it returns failed(19).

Thank you!

Comment: Once ejected all knowledge of the device is lost so you will need to rescan (E.g. `CM_Reenumerate_DevNode_Ex`)